# Eclipse error : The type Put.Request is not visible

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, knox-gateway

I'm using the knox client dsl from a Java class like so:

```
package org.apache.camel;

...
import org.apache.hadoop.gateway.shell.Hadoop;
import org.apache.hadoop.gateway.shell.hdfs.Hdfs;

public class KnoxProducer extends DefaultProducer {


    public KnoxProducer(KnoxEndpoint endpoint) {
        super(endpoint);
        this.endpoint = endpoint;
    }

    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        ...
        Hadoop session = Hadoop.login( gateway, username, password );
        Hdfs.put(session).text(body).to(path).now();

        //   ^ Eclipse Error: The type Put.Request is not visible

        session.shutdown();
    }
}
```

However, Eclipse is showing an error:

```
 The type Put.Request is not visible
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug, the details are here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KNOX-713

It is fixed for Apache Knox 0.9.1

Answer (score 0):

Still it is throwing error as Put.Response is not visible . so the better approach is add the following dependency file in the maven.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.knox</groupId>
    <artifactId>gateway-shell</artifactId>
    <version>0.14.0</version>
</dependency>
```